# Jquery slider does not work bxslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to implement bxslider on a webpage and it does not work.
code:

```
<ul class="bxslider">
    <li><img src="{url href='images/icon_telefon.png'}"></li>
    <li><img src="{url href='images/icon_telefon.png'}"></li>
    <li><img src="{url href='images/icon_telefon.png'}"></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the function:

```
(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider(
    mode: 'vertical',
    auto: true
  );
});
```

But the other functions who work are written in another syntax:

```
(function() {
  var po = document.createElement('script');
  po.type = 'text/javascript';
  po.async = true;
  po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';

  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
})();
```

Is the way that I have declared the function wrong?

Comment: stupid question, but do you have jquery and bxslider library loaded on your page? Also, your html is missing some `<`

Comment: and change `$('.bxslider').bxSlider(
      mode: 'vertical',
       auto: true
    );` to `$('.bxslider').bxSlider( {
      mode: 'vertical',
       auto: true }
    );`

Comment: Yes I do have them loaded, I did that to HTML on purpose so I can post it here. But the problem is if I declare function as $document.ready..... I get an uncaught error type in my console. I have tried the thing with { } but it does not work sir.

Comment: change `(function(){
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider(
      mode: 'vertical',
       auto: true
    );
 });` to `$(document).ready( function(){
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
      mode: 'vertical',
       auto: true
    });
 });`.

Comment: post your exact console error.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).bxSlider is not a function

Comment: that means that bxSlider is not loaded. Please ensure that bxSlider is loaded BEFORE it is called.

Comment: What does that mean, kind sir?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103345/discussion-between-flav-flavius-and-mani).